# Why doesn't OpenLayers Plugin 1.3.6 show in Internet menu on Ubuntu 14?

Tags: ubuntu, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I installed QGIS 2.8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit (from repository http://qgis.org/debian trusty)
I installed OpenLayers Plugin 1.3.6

It doesn't show in main menu (Internet) like on Mac
Do I miss something or is a problem with Ubuntu ?

Comment: On Ubuntu suppose to be Under Extension menu. But it is not there.

Comment: No, the plugin has been moved from the `Plugins` menu to the `Web` menu some time ago. Do you have a folder `/home/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/´ ? Do you have other plugins working? Same version is working for me, with QGIS 2.8.1 from ubuntugis unstable on 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I disabled all plugins then activate only OpenLayers plugin and the web/internet menu came back.

Comment: By adding Qgiscloud plugin you can see under Service tab  the layers provide by OpenLayer. A kind of turnaround.